# Delete .files and .chunk with GridFSBucket

Tags: node.js, mongodb, gridfs

I'm trying to delete both .files and .chunk data but all the posts that I have found are either outdated or do not apply to my issue.

This is my backend route:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const config = require("config");
const db = config.get("mongoURI");
let gfs;
const conn = mongoose.createConnection(db);
conn.once("open", () => {
  gfs = new mongoose.mongo.GridFSBucket(conn.db, {
    bucketName: "photos"
  });
});

router.delete('/:imageID', async (req, res) => {
    gfs.delete({_id: req.params.imageID, root:"photos"}, function(error){
      test.equal(error, null);
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Solved! to succesfully delete GridFS .files and .chunks just find the obj_id and do `gfs.delete( obj_id)`
Code:

```
router.delete("/:imageID", auth, async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const post = await Post.findOne({ image: req.params.imageID });
    console.log(post);
    if (post.user != req.user.id) {
      res.status(401).send("Invalid credentials");
    }

// Here:
    const obj_id = new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.imageID);
    gfs.delete( obj_id );

    await post.remove();
    res.json("successfully deleted image!");
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
    res.status(500).send("Server Error");
  }
});
```